# PHP MVC Delete Function Controller

Tags: php

I have made a MVC site that is displaying a databases records, each record is printed on its own line with a delete button beside it. I am having some issues with the delete button. When I click the delete button I am trying to sending it to my controller to handle.

The issues I am having are

- I cant send the row id from the button.php to the controller (Have a strong suspicion that the code is wrong)
- The delet function in the controller doesnt work, in the code below I have hard coded in the row ID that I want to delete but when I click the delete button I get the following error

  Syntax error in SQL statement.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id=27' at line 1

**Button.php**

```
<?php
$result=$itemsDAO->getItems();
foreach ($result as $row) {
$uid = $row['id'];
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<input id='action' type='hidden' name='action' value='deleteItem' />
<p>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="hidden" id="fID" name="uid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Delete">
    </div>
</div>
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

**Delete function in the controller**

```
        function deleteItem($parameters) {
        $id = $parameters["fID"];

        if ($this->model->deleteItem( $id )) {
            $this->model->hasDeleteFailed = false;
            $this->model->setDeleteItemConfirmation();
            return (true);
        }
        else
            $this->model->deleteItemError ( DELETE_ITEM_ERROR_STR );
    }
```

**Delete SQL**

```
    public function deleteItem($id) {
    $delId = $id;
    $sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM items";
    $sqlQuery .= " WHERE id=$delId;";

    $result = $this->getDbManager () -> executeQuery ( $sqlQuery );
}
```

Comment: Full sql query please. And give, what you have in $_POST, while pressing `delete` button?

Comment: You are sending your POST request from `button.php` to `index.php`. Is this our controller?

Comment: updated to show the SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this steps :

1. Check whether `$parameters` is properly passed to the `deleteItem` function (use `echo $parameters` or somthing)
2. If so check the query (`DELETE * FROM 'thetable' WHERE id = $id`)

Normally in a MVC site parameters pass through (`site_url/controller/method/parameter`) url. But while you are using a form, it's need to be a mechanism to capture your form variables.

Comment: I dunno if anything is being sent from the buttons.php becuase when i try echo the parameters from the function deleteItem() nothing happens

Comment: Use this link. It may give a idea how to use form variables in MVC : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690405/how-to-pass-post-variables-with-mvc

Comment: thanks for the help, can you tell me if the `button.php` is right? cause when i run the page some of the code is printed out along with the button

Comment: 1. It's seems wrong. You can't use HTML directly inside php . Either close it using `?>` (before start HTML) or use HTML  as strings.
2. Have to end the `foreach` end of the page using `<?php }`

Comment: I have edited the above code to take in you comments but I can seem to shift the SQL syntax error, can you see what else could be wrong?

Comment: Check whether `$id` has passed or not. If so please update your question with SQL syntax error.